# Twitter Clone in NODEJS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-oauth

I'm very new to NodeJS in fact this is my first project and i have been asked to build a twitter clone that allows users to Login/Signup into their account and view their timeline as well as make tweets. I have built a simple HTML form and now want it to trigger the Sign In process on the app.js file in my folder.I have already created an app on twitter and i have the consumer_key and consumer_secret values.I'm using the twitter npm module to connect and it is connecting directly into my account without redirecting to the authentication page and i can only see the tweets in my nodeJS console whereas i want them retrieved and displaying on an HTML document and maybe with twitter's embedded timelines too. I'll post my HTML and app.js code here please help me out with the remaining part of the code to complete this project thank you.

This is the Form tag of my html document:

```
 <form >
  <button  id="btnLogin" type="button" onclick="popper()"  class="button  buttonBlue">Login
<div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
</button>
</form>
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function popper(){
  $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
  $.get('/', function (data) {
  console.log("Inside Script Tag of form");
  });
  });}
    </script>

//Now here is my App.jS code
//Please ignore some other API's ive tried alot of stuff
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var url = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit = require('twit');
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;
var mtwitter = require('mtwitter');
var Twitter = require('twitter');

 //Use Express JS here to directly parse Static Content
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); //Display Static Content From Public Folder
app.listen(8000);
console.log("Server Listening at 127.0.0.1:8000")
console.log("Initializing Twitter API Please wait a moment:")


//npm twitter API Most widey used 

var client = new Twitter({
consumer_key: 'myconsumer_key',         //note im hiding these values on stackoverflow
consumer_secret: 'myconsumer_secret',
access_token_key: 'myaccess_token',
access_token_secret: 'my_access_token_secret'
});

client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
 if (!error) {
 console.log(tweets);  //all my tweets are displayed in cmd here 
}
});
```

I want the user to redirect to the twitter authentication page after clicking a button and display their tweets and post tweets on another HTML form and even better if theyre in the twitter embedded timeline/tweet formats.